Bearded homeless man shaves beard to get revenge
I saw this movie within the last 12 months, and I'm willing to bet it was released in 2012-2016 (U.S./English).
It starts off with a bearded homeless man living out of a car who upon hearing the news from a local police officer (I remember she was black) (she apparently checks up on him) that someone who murdered one of his family members was released from prison.
He then collects what he has, (somehow) gets the car working, shaves his beard, and travels to the city where the ex-con lives, and kills him with a knife in the bathroom of a bar.
I remember he stabs the tires of the family car of the person he killed so that they cannot follow him, but after realizes he left his keys in the bathroom so has to instead steal the car he just sabotaged (and I think there was someone still in the car).
Ring any bells?

Embarrassingly, I just found it:
Blue Ruin (2013)

A mysterious outsider's quiet life is turned upside down when he returns to his childhood home to carry out an act of vengeance. Proving himself an amateur assassin, he winds up in a brutal fight to protect his estranged family.


